# Jquery - How to read a txt file and append into a form

Tags: jquery, file, append

I have several text files like that content something like this:

```
<select name='CitySearch' id='CitySearch'>
   <option value=''>- Select a City -</option>
   <option value=''>-----------</option>
   <option value='Bejuco'>Bejuco</option>
   <option value='Esterillos'>Esterillos</option>
</select>
```

Of course each one are different content. No matter about the filename, we can use example.txt

I have a map and if you click in any region the script must to append the txt inside a form. This is the function when you make click:

```
// Assigning an action to the click event
$(this).click(function(e) {
    var country_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', '');

    if($("div[id^='area_']").length = 1){
        $("div[id^='area_']").remove(); //remove the last inserted select option
        }
var append_data = '<div id="area_'+country_id+'">**INSERT HTML FROM FILE HERE**</div>';
$("#text_boxes").append(append_data); //append new select options in main div
    });
```

I know that is something basicall but I have not too much experience with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get the contents of a file and insert it into the matched element.

```
var append_data = '<div id="area_'+country_id+'"></div>';
$("#text_boxes").append(append_data); //append new select options in main div

$("#area_"+country_id).load("path/to/file.html"); // load html file
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an ajax call on file url and append response to string.

```
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        var country_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', '');

        if($("div[id^='area_']").length = 1){
            $("div[id^='area_']").remove(); //remove the last inserted select option
            }
          appendNewResult(country_id);
        });
function appendNewResult(country_id){
        $.get(filepath,function(response){
                      var append_data = '<div id="area_'+country_id+'">' + response +'</div>';
    $("#text_boxes").append(append_data); //append new select options in main div

        });
}
```

Comment: This uses `$.get()` to the exact same thing as my `.load()` answer but with a few more lines of code. It might be worth noting that this method allows you to do more in the complete handler. Both are applicable based on your requirements.